# cakephp: access a controller from a plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm using cake 2.2. I would like to modify a UserMgmt plugin to use a couple of models and controllers from the parent app.

I have a view in the plugin that need to access the 'Hotels' controller and the 'GetHotels' action.  My plugin view has:

```
  $this->Js->get('#UserRegionId')->event('change',
  $this->Js->request(array(
     'controller'=>'Hotels',
 'action'=>'GetHotels'
), array(
'update'=>'#UserCategoryId',
'async' => true,
'method' => 'post',
'dataExpression'=>true,
'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true))
    )
)
);
```

I suspect I need to add app::uses before the class definition on the UserMgmt.UsersController

```
  App::uses('Hotel','Model');
  App::uses('Hotels','Controller');
```

but I'm it is not working.

I got the error Error:

```
  Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class HotelsController could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the view isn't accessing the controller internally. `$this->Js->request()` is calling a url via ajax.  So you don't need `App::uses()`.

Set the controller/action to lowercase.  urls are usually always lowercase (or at least they should be for sanity's sake!).

```
'controller'=>'hotels',
'action'=>'get_hotels'
```

To test if those are valid, access the path directly yourself:

```
http://yourdomain.com/hotels/get_hotels
```

Comment: point about lower case duly noted. all has been changed.  I can access the url directly but I still get the error when it is called by the plugin.  The code works fine in views that are not in the plugin.

Comment: Strange. Try using a string for the url, just to see if you get the error. `$this->Js->request('/hotels/gethotels', array(...`.  Also, check the stack trace for the error to figure out where it's coming from. I'm assuming from `Router` class.